# Stack overflow during recursive directory traversing using the Win32 API in C++

Tags: winapi, recursion, directory, stack, overflow

I've been trying to figure out why this is giving me a stack overflow for hours, probably something simple that I just am missing, it was working earlier until I messed with it to try to clean it up. Anyways some fresh eyes would be greatly appreciated.

```
int scan(LPSTR szPath, LPSTR pattern) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA WFD;
    HANDLE hSearch;
    CHAR szFullPath [MAX_PATH+1] = "";
    PVOID OldValue = NULL;

    if( Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue) ) 
    {

        PathCombine(szFullPath, szPath, "*"); 
        hSearch = FindFirstFile(szFullPath, &WFD);
        if ( hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
            while(FindNextFile(hSearch,&WFD)) {
                if(strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"..") || strcmp(WFD.cFileName,".")){
                    FindNextFile(hSearch,&WFD);
                }
                if(WFD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
                    PathCombine(szFullPath, szPath, WFD.cFileName);
                    scan(szFullPath, pattern);
                } 
            }
            FindClose(hSearch);
        }

        PathCombine(szFullPath, szPath, pattern);
        hSearch = FindFirstFile(szFullPath, &WFD);
        if( hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
            while( FindNextFile(hSearch, &WFD) ) {
                if(!(WFD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
                    PathCombine(szFullPath, szPath, WFD.cFileName);
                int index = SendDlgItemMessage(ghWnd, IDLIST, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)szFullPath);

            }
        }

        FindClose(hSearch);
        if ( FALSE == Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue) )
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
    if(strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"..") || strcmp(WFD.cFileName,".")){
        FindNextFile(hSearch,&WFD);
    }
```

Add a "continue" statement to fix the issue.  The check for "." and ".." is good.  The problem is the code breaks if they are adjacent.

**Edit:**  Specifically, add "continue" after FindNextFile in this code block.

Comment: That did fix the infinite recursion, but for some reason now nothing gets past that if statement, its treating every file and directory as if its '..' or '.'

Comment: Changed it to     if(strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"..") == 0 || strcmp(WFD.cFileName,".") == 0)    which works perfectly, not sure why, but thanks.

Comment: @user873294: It works because `strcmp` doesn't return true/false -- rather, it returns -1, 0, or 1: 1 to indicate second string greater than first, 0 to indicate equality, and -1 to indicate first string greater than second.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change in the first loop:

```
if(strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"..") || strcmp(WFD.cFileName,".")){
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Added this, which fixed the stack overflow but even if cFilename != .. or . it goes to continue, I've been stepping through in the debugger and can't figure out why it wont exclude real directories & files from this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you are probably getting an infinite recursion by accidentally including the local directory in your enumeration, which will then include the local directory again, etc.

But even if you solve this, you are calling `scan` recursively, which can easily cause your stack to blow if you're not very careful, and understand your memory requirements, stack limits, etc, very well.

If you solve the infinite recursion problem, and still get a stack overflow, the common solution is to implement your own stack, rather than relying on recursive function calls.

See [the Stack (data structure) article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) for some amount of detail on how the stack works.